# Java generics incompatible types while subclassing

Tags: java, generics

While sub classing from generic class type/Formal type parameter `T/E` with valid class type/Actual type parameter say e.g. `Type/String` there are many combinations occurs and that confusing which one to use and when?

```
    public class SubClass<T> implements SuperIfc<T>  <-- It is straight forward to understand
    public class SubClass<T> implements SuperIfc<Type>

    public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc<T>
    public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>
    public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc
    public class SubClass implements SuperIfc<Type>
    public class SubClass implements SuperIfc<T>    <--- Hope we cannot declare <T> in his case while initialising SubClass.

    // Bounded type parameter
    public class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>
    public class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<T> <-- Looks <T> at SuperIfc also refers <T extends Type>, and no need to declare it again at SuperIfc.

    // Recursive type bound
    public class SubClass<T extends Comparable<T>>> implements SuperIfc<T>
    public class SubClass<T extends Comparable<T>>> implements SuperIfc<Type>
```

So that i can be more clearer on solving `incompatible types while subclassing`

Case_1:

```
public class Test {

    interface TestIfc {

        public static <T extends TestIfc> T of(int choice) {

            if(choice == 1) {
                return new TestImpl(); <-- PROB_1: incompatible type error 
            } else {
                return new SomeOtherTestImpl(); //incompatible type error
            }
        }
    }

    static class TestImpl implements TestIfc {}
    
    static class SomeOtherTestImpl<T extends TestIfc> implements TestIfc {

        //The below method also having same error though with declaration
        public T of() {
            return new TestImpl();  <-- PROB_2: incompatible type error
        }
    }
}
```

Case_1: PROB_1: return type is `T extends TestIfc` and returned `TestImpl implements TestIf` So what is wrong?

Case_1: PROB_2: Similar to PROB_1, how to rectify without external casting. Please help.

---

Case_2:

```
public interface SuperIfc<T> {
    
    public T create(Object label);
}

class Type {

    public static Type of(){
         return new Type();
    }
}
------

public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>{

    @Override
    public Type create() {
        return Type.of(); <---- PROB_1: cannot resolve method
    }
}
-------

public class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>{

    @Override
    public Type create() {
        return Type.of(); <---- PROB_1: is resolved
    }
}

SuperIfc<Type> object = new SubClass(); <-- PROB_2 Unchecked assignement warning
SuperIfc<Type> object = new SubClass<TypeImpl>(); <-- PROB_3: bound should extend Type
```

1. I would like to know how to resolve Case_2, PROB_1 and PROB_2 together?
2. How to write subclass for generic super class with class types and what are the rules?
3. What should be taken care when changing generic `T` to class `Type` while subclassing? may be the difference between below and when to use?

   ```
    public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>
    public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc
    public class SubClass implements SuperIfc<Type>
    public class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>
    public class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<T>
    public class SubClass<T> implements SuperIfc<Type>
   ```

Comment: PROB_2 you should write `SuperIfc<TypeImpl> object = new SubClass<>();` otherwise you're using raw types.

Comment: PROB_1 your method shouldn't be a generic at all. `public static TestIfc of(int choice)`

Comment: Above one i agree, you are right! @matt

Answer (score 1):

In the first `of()` method, the method can return any type that implements `InformationIfc`, but your method always returns a specific implementation - `InformationImpl` - which is not acceptable.

For example, if you had some other class `SomeOtherInformationImpl` that implements that interface, the caller of that method would be allowed to write:

```
SomeOtherInformationImpl i = InformationImpl.of();
```

but your method doesn't return a `SomeOtherInformationImpl`.

The second `of()` method has the same issue as the first method.
If you instantiated your class with:

```
InformationImpl i = new InformationImpl<SomeOtherInformationImpl>();
```

the `of()` method would have to return a `SomeOtherInformationImpl`, not a `InformationImpl`.

Comment: In my second method i told i can declare it in class in code comment

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Oh, in that case the second method has the same error as the first method.

Comment: plusOne butt still not covienced, let me go through your answer again.

Comment: I just updated my answer with the method not to return a specific implementation. Still same problem.

Comment: Also i dont understand how caller would allowed to write `SomeOtherInformationImpl i = InformationImpl.of();`? The caller can expect only `InformationIfc i = InformationImpl.of();` right?

Answer (score 1):

**Problems with case one.**

> PROB_1: return type is T extends TestIfc

Why do you have a generic here at all?. Since you have a static method I can do.

```
TestIfc broken = TestIfc<SomeOtherImplementation>.of(0);
```

`SomeOtherImplementation` is not a `TestImpl`. This is broken by design. What you really want is.

```
 public static TestIfc of(int choice)
```

Next.

> static class SomeOtherTestImpl<T extends TestIfc> implements TestIfc {

`TestIfc` is not parameterized, `SomeOtherTestImp` is, but it is completely unrelated to the interface you're implementing. Not to mention, TestIfc has a **static method** `of` that has nothing to do with the interface.

If I had to guess, I would think you want.

```
interface TestIfc<T>{}
static class TestImpl implements TestIfc<TestImpl> {}
static class SomeOtherTestImpl<T extends TestIfc> implements TestIfc<T>{}
```

That is the best I could come up with, because it is unclear what you actually want to happen.

**Your examples for question 3**

```
public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>
```

This is broken, because `SubClass<Type>` declares `Type` to be the name of a generic parameter. It puts no restriction on the type, hence you get the method not found error.

```
public class SubClass<Type> implements SuperIfc
```

Broken, makes a generic parameter named `Type`, has nothing to do with your raw type version of `SuperIfc`

```
public SubClass implements SuperIfc<Type>
```

This is good.

```
public class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<Type>
public class SubClass<T> implements SuperIfc<Type>
```

These are both good, but the T has no relation to the SuperIfc parameter, hence your implementation would be.

```
public Type create(Object label);
```

The first generic parameter says the name you're going to use through the class.

Comment: Thanks! @matt, plusOne; will review it and respond.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long answer, but please read through it (at least case 1 and the very end, you can skip over problem 2's solution in case 2 if you wish)

### Case 1

#### Problem 1:

Your problem here is that the compiler cannot prove that `T` is the same as `TestImpl` or `SomeOtherTestImpl`. What if there was another class, call it `TestFoo`, that implemented `TestIfc`? Then, if you called the method as `TestIfc.<TestFoo>of(1)`, you would expect an object of type `TestFoo`, but you would instead get a `TestImpl`, which is wrong. The compiler doesn't want you doing that, so it throws an error. What you should do is just remove the generics, like so:

```
public static TestImpl of(int choice) {
  if(choice == 1) {
    return new TestImpl();
  } else {
    return new SomeOtherTestImpl();
  }
}
```

And then you can safely call `TestIfc.of`.

#### Problem 2:

This is basically the same thing. The compiler can't prove that the type parameter `T` of `SomeOtherTestImpl` is the same as `TestImpl`. What if you have an object like this (where `TestFoo` does not extend `TestImpl` but implements `TestIfc`)?

```
SomeOtherTestImpl<TestFoo> testImpl = ...;
```

And then you try to call the `of` method like this:

```
TestFoo testFoo = testImpl.of();
```

Can you see the problem here? Your `of` method returns a `TestImpl`, but you expect it to return a `TestFoo` because `T` is `TestFoo`. The compiler stops you from doing that. Again, you should just get rid of the generics:

```
public TestImpl of() {
  return new TestImpl(); //This works now
}
```

---

### Case 2

#### Problem 1

This problem is caused simply because you named your type parameter the same thing as your class - `Type`. When you changed the name of your type parameter to, say, `T`, it'll work because now `Type` is the name of a class. Before, your type parameter `Type` was hiding the class `Type`.

However, again, there is no need for a type parameter, since, you can just do this, and it'll satisfy all constraints.

```
public class SubClass implements SuperIfc<Type> {
    @Override
    public Type create() {
        return Type.of();
    }
}
```

#### Problem 2:

The unchecked assignment is because you didn't provide type arguments to `SubClass` when you did

```
SuperIfc<Type> object = new SubClass();
```

This can be fixed by either explicitly giving `Type` to `SubClass`:

```
SuperIfc<Type> object = new SubClass<Type>();
```

or by putting in an empty diamond (which I much prefer). This second approach means that the compiler can infer by itself that by `new Subclass<>()`, you mean `new Subclass<Type>()`.

```
SuperIfc<Type> object = new SubClass<>();
```

---

Why the compiler complains:

That constructor call (`new Subclass()`) is basically like calling a method that looks like `public SubClass makeNewSubClass() {...}`. In fact, let's replace that statement above with this one, which will cause the same warning.

```
SuperIfc<Type> object = makeNewSubClass();
```

`SubClass` normally takes 1 type parameter (call it `T`), but here, it's not given any type parameters. That means that `T` could be anything, any class that extends `Type` (because of the constraint `SubClass<T extends Type>`).

You might thinking that if `T` is always going to be a subclass of `Type`, it should work all right, because the type of `object` above is `SuperIfc<Type>`. Assume there's a class like this - `class TypeFoo extends Type` - and that the method `makeNewSubClass` actually returns an object of type `SubClass<TypeFoo>` (`new SubClass<TypeFoo>()`).

Because of this, you expect object to be `SuperIfc<Type>` but it's actually `SubClass<TypeFoo>`. You probably think that that's all right, because after all, `TypeFoo` is a subclass of `Type`, right? Well, Java's generics are actually [*invariant*](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-java-generic-types-covariance-and-contravariance-88f4c19763d2/), which means that for the compiler, `SubClass<TypeFoo>` is not a subclass of `SuperIfc<Type>` - it thinks they're 2 completely unrelated types. Don't ask me - I have no idea why :). Even `SubClass<TypeFoo>` isn't considered the same as or a subclass of `SubClass<Type>`!

That's why the compiler emits a warning - because raw types (that's what you call it when you have `new SubClass()` without giving type arguments) could represent anything. As for why it emits a warning and not an error - generics were introduced in Java 5, so for code before that to compile, the compiler lets you off with just a warning.

#### Problem 3:

According to the error, the type argument you gave (`TypeImpl`) should extend `Type`. This is because you defined `SubClass` as `class SubClass<T extends Type> ...`. Here, you are giving `TypeImpl` as an argument for `T`, and so `TypeImpl` must extend `Type`, so all you need to do is put do `class TypeImpl extends Type` to solve that particular error.

However, even after you do that, you'll get an "incompatible types" error because, as I said earlier when talking about Problem 2, `SuperIfc<Type>` is not considered a supertype of `SubClass<TypeImpl>` even if `TypeImpl` extends `Type`.

You can do this

```
SuperIfc<TypeImpl> object = new SubClass<TypeImpl>();
```

or you can do this

```
SuperIfc<? extends Type> object = new SubClass<TypeImpl>();
```

In the second solution, we lose the information of what exactly `T` is in `SuperIfc<T>`; all we know is that it extends `Type`. The benefit of the second one is that you can later reassign any `SubClass` object to it (which doesn't work with the first version because it only allows `SubClass<TypeImpl>`:

```
SuperIfc<? extends Type> object = new SubClass<TypeImpl>();
object = new SubClass<Type>(); //works great
```

#### Alternative solution for Case 2

What it seems like you want to do is return objects of different type depending on type parameters. That's not really possible to do, since type parameters are erased at runtime. There are workarounds, though.

Here's one way to do it with a functional interface. It involves no casting and ensures type safety.

```
//This is the functional interface. You can also use Supplier here, of course
interface Constructor<T> {
  T create();
}

class SubClass<T extends Type> implements SuperIfc<T> {

  public Constructor<T> ctor;

  public SubClass(Constructor<T> ctor) {
    this.ctor = ctor;
  }

  @Override
  public T create(Object label) {
    return ctor.create();
  }
}

class Type {}
class TypeImpl extends Type{}
```

By using a `Constructor` object, you will know that the returned `Type` object will always be of the right type. This is very easy to apply to your existing code - you don't need to write your own `ConstructorImpl` classes or anything.

You can now write this, and all you need to add is a method reference to the constructor (`Type::new`).

```
SuperIfc<Type> object1 = new SubClass<>(Type::new);

SuperIfc<? extends Type> object2 = new SubClass<>(TypeImpl::new);
```

With lambdas, you can also write this in a slightly more verbose way:

```
SuperIfc<TypeImpl> object = new SubClass<>(() -> new TypeImpl());
---
SuperIfc<? extends Type> object = new SubClass<>(() -> new TypeImpl());
```